# How to Install QT3 Runtime Library?

Tags: software-installation

I was trying to install the driver for my USB modem on Ubuntu 14.04. I ran

```
sudo ./install.sh
```

It outputted the following in the terminal

```
..................start install.................
*** Check for root...
```

And then this message appeared

[image]

I'm wondering how to install this library?

Thank you!

---

**Update:** the name of the modem is **ZTE MF180S**

Comment: It's obsolete now. What's that program?

Comment: @enedil if you mean the software for the USB, it's the driver for it. Do you think there's any other solution?

Comment: Give us the name of the modem.

Comment: @enedil updated my question with it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I, thankfully, was able to get my USB modem to work by installing *libusb* and *usb_modeswitch*. The instructions for these can be found [here](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/#intro).