# Install USB modem ZTE WCDMA on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, usb-modem

I am unable to install my USB Modem on Ubuntu 14.04, When I do:
`sudo ./install.sh`, I get the following error:

> This software will not run until you install "QT3 Runtime Library". You can refer to Operaing System installation CD or Homepage to find out the QT3 Runtime Library installation package. This installation process will not continue until you install QT3 Runtime Library first.

I then installed **USB_ModeSwitch** following these instructions here http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/

USB_ModeSwitch was successfully installed and then when I try to install the USB Modem again, I get the same error.

I don't know what to do next. Here the result of `lsusb` command:

```
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 19d2:0117 ZTE WCDMA Technologies MSM 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

I think that my USB Modem is being detected as a USB CD-ROM.
Here is the result of `dmesg | tail` command:

```
[ 3934.165521] scsi9 : usb-storage 1-4:1.3
[ 3935.165332] scsi 9:0:0:0: CD-ROM            ZTE      USB SCSI CD-ROM  2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 3935.165937] scsi 9:0:0:1: Direct-Access     ZTE      MMC Storage      2.31 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[ 3935.175561] sr1: scsi-1 drive
[ 3935.176136] sr 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr1
[ 3935.176805] sr 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 5
[ 3935.177554] sd 9:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[ 3935.185897] sd 9:0:0:1: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[ 3935.448189] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 1
[ 3935.449931] ISOFS: changing to secondary root
```

Comment: Have you tried installing the `QT3 Runtime Library`?

Comment: @Wayne_Yux I searched a lot for this library but I've found nothing. I viewed this question here http://askubuntu.com/questions/503448/how-to-install-qt3-runtime-library#comments-503448
Someone commented that it's obsolete now.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the `install.sh` script, you'll notice:

```
function check_qt3
{
  QT3LIB=$(find /usr/lib -name "libqt-mt.so*")
  echo $QT3LIB
  if [ "$QT3LIB" ];then
      echo "check QT3 Runtime Library successfully."
  else
       mymessagebox "Sorry This software will not run until you install "QT3 Runtime Library". You can refer to Operaing System installation CD or Homepage to find out the QT3 Runtime Library installation package. This installation process will not continue until you install QT3 Runtime Library first."
  exit -1
fi
}
```

The script checks the `/usr/lib/libqt-mt.so*`. If the file is not found, the message will prompt you to install Qt3.  After this, installation can continue.

To install Qt3: 
[How to install qt3-dev-tools package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/386254/how-to-install-qt3-dev-tools-package)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just work with your modem then you can try the UBUNTU's builtin feature.

1. go to **setting**.
2. search for **connections** in **network setting**.
3. add a **new connection** as **mobile broadband**.
4. select your **device**, **country** and **Provider**
5. save and I hope it will work without installing the modem driver